# Firefox does not render stylesheet immediately?

Tags: css, firefox

I'm not sure if this a settings problem or an HTML problem, but on a page layout I'm working on, Firefox does not render the stylesheet immediately. Meaning for maybe half a second I can see the unstyled page, then the stylesheet kicks in and it renders as I expect.

All my stylesheets are in external css files loaded in the head tag. I'm not encountering this on Flock (which is a Firefox variant) nor on Google Chrome/IE.

Any idea how to avoid it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try disabling firebug.

Comment: Wow, and this has been bugging me for months! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Firebug definitely slows down the page render time.  Brutally so.

Additionally, Install yslow: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ in firefox to make sure that your page is optimized to its fullest.

Comment: Make sure you understand that Yslow is for _large_ volume websites, and some of the items (CDN, E-tags) may not apply to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Show us the page! Is it valid?

You might want to search for "flash of unstyled content" or "FOUC" and see what comes up, that's the commonly-used phrase for this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the platform, but this can also happen with the Visual Studio built-in web server if IPv6 is enabled in Firefox. See http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/07/speeding-up-communication-between-firefox-and-visual-studios-built-in-web-server/

Answer (score 0):

In my case turning off Firebug didn't help. From the other hand I happend to use **@import** in my css and when i removed it - the **FOUC** (Flash Of Unstyled Content) was gone. That is very strange because this behaviour is mostly referred to **IE** (http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/)